# Ajax call inside of loop needs to be synchronized

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, prototypejs, asynccallback

I have a coding issue where I want to loop thru and call an ajax call but I dont want another request to be sent until the first one is complete.  I have tried setting it to asyc = false and adding an onsuccess callback.  But it seems like the loop is continuing to run which gives me responses out of order and parallel requests.

// This function is used to generate  a numeric val and passes it along in the success callback

```
  function duplicateOmsid(totalAmount, omsid) {
var url = '/portal/GetBulkCopyAmountServlet';
var errorString;


new Ajax.Request(
url, {
    method: 'post',
    parameters: {
        totalAmount: totalAmount,
        omsid: omsid
    },        
    async: false,
    onSuccess: function(transport) {
        dataResponse = transport.responseText.evalJSON();
          createWorkflow(totalAmount, omsid, dataResponse);


    },
```

.....

// Function used to loop thru and call the duplicate workflow ajax call

```
function createWorkflow(totalAmount, omsid, bulkAmount) {
            var amountProccessed = 0; 
            for( i = 0; amountProccessed < totalAmount; i++ ) {  // Loop through source
                var duplicateAmt;

                if (totalAmount < 11){
                    duplicateAmt = totalAmount
                }else{
                     duplicateAmt = amountProccessed + dataResponse < totalAmount ? dataResponse : totalAmount - amountProccessed
                }


           duplicateWorkflow(totalAmount, omsid, duplicateAmt, amountProccessed);
           amountProccessed += bulkAmount;
    }
     }
```

// Function used to create the workflow ajax call - the success handler is updating the user.

```
 function duplicateWorkflow( totalAmount, omsid, bulkAmount, amountProccessed){
        amountProccessed += bulkAmount;
        var url = '/portal/CreateWorkFlowServlet';
        var errorString;
        new Ajax.Request(
        url, {
            method: 'post',     
            parameters: {
                totalAmount: totalAmount,
                omsid: omsid,
                bulkAmount: bulkAmount
            },  
            async: false,
            onSuccess: function(transport) {

             var div = document.getElementById('progress');

         if( amountProccessed > totalAmount){
             div.innerHTML = totalAmount + ' out of ' + totalAmount + ' Processed ' ;

             alert (totalAmount + 'Items successfully duplicated  ')
         }else{
             div.innerHTML = amountProccessed + ' out of ' + totalAmount + ' Processed ' ;
         }
            },

            onFailure: function(e) {
                }
            },

            onException: function(e) {
                }
            },

        });
 }
```

Comment: Better try to asynchronize the loop :-)

Comment: There is no `async` option in [Prototypejs Ajax](http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, the way to sequentialize async code using raw Javascript is to use recursion instead of a for loop.

```
var urls = [ /*...*/ ];

function loop(i, onDone){
    if(i >= urls.length){
        //base case
        onDone( theResultOfProcessingTheAjaxRequests );
    }else{
        Ajax.Request(urls[i], {
            onsuccess: function(){
                loop(i+1, onDone);
            }
        });
    }
}

loop(0, function(result){
    console.log("all done");
});
```

Note that I converted `i` to a function parameter, to keep it scoped to the looping function. If you wanted, you could declare it outside, just like you did in the for loop:

```
var urls = [ /*...*/ ];
var i = 0;

function loop(onDone){
   //...
   i = i+1;
   loop(onDone);
}
```

Additionally, I added an "onDone" callback to the looping function to help the async code look a bit more like the sync version. The idea is that by using a return callback, the `loop` function doesn't need to know what function called it and where it should jump to after its done its job - in the end, calling `onDone(x)` is a bit similar to doing `return x`. Of course, you could have hardcoded the return function if you wanted.

```
function afterAjax(){
    console.log("all done");
}

function loop(){
    if(i >= urls.length){
       afterAjax();
    }
    //...
}

loop();
```

---

Finally, coding recursive loops like this is a bit annoying and there are many libraries out there that provide functions to encapsulate these hight level sequentialization and parallelization patterns. In particular, error handling (try-catch) is specially hard to do by hand with callbacks. If you are doing any more non-tricial Async stuff I would highly recommend looking into some of these libraries.

Comment: @user3461385: You can click the green checkmark to mark the answer as accepted :) (You can also upvote any answers you find helpful)

Comment: I tried.  Looks like Ill have to come back when my reputation up to 15 before I can up-vote and accept